# datatables hidden column date sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have following string date column in datatables.
I need to sort the table data **onload** based on the following column

[image]

Thank you,
Sri

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do initial sorting in DataTables:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

There should be a default date sort but here you could find some helpful plugins that will do the job if it is not working as intended:

https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/